# Adding a texture to a node programmatically ARKit

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm trying to make my node (object) red in ARKit programmatically, but it still shows up in my scene in white. Where am I going wrong?

```
let object = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/abc.stl")
let node = SCNNode()

let nodeArray = object!.rootNode.childNodes

for childNode in nodeArray {
    node.addChildNode(childNode)
}

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
//material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/Metal.jpg")
node.geometry?.materials = [material]
```

Comment: Add code, where you're set upping the node, please.

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev I just did

Answer (score 0):

I guess the "node.geometry?" is nil.

Comment: Why is that? Doesn't a 3D object have to have a geometry?

Comment: It's optional. e.x., init(geometry: SCNGeometry?) I don't know that did you set up your geometry for the node yet. So you can check it is nil or not.